# Python: Copy a file in google drive into a specific folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, pydrive

I'm making a spreadsheet that I need to reset every single week, I'm trying to use the PyDrive API to make a copy of the file, which works perfectly with the code below.

My problem is that i cant specify which folder I want to save the copy in. I would like to have a folder called "archive" which contains all my backups. Is this possible, using PyDrive and if so, how? Thanks!

```
## Create a new Document in Google Drive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
folder = "########"
title = "Copy of my other file"
file = "############"
drive.auth.service.files().copy(fileId=file,
                           body={"parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink",
                                 "id": folder}], 'title': title}).execute()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you __are__ specifying the destination folder with `body={"parents":[...]}`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am working on similar things ,  but copy the entire folder to another folder

Comment: seems `"kind": "drive#fileLink"` is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @Rawing I figured it out. It was specified in the "folder" variable

Comment: You can now [accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark your question as answered :)